# Custom keyboard like gif keyboard in android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I'm developing a custom Android keyboard like gif keyboard(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bo.pic.android.keyboard&hl=ko).

When i click a specific button, I want to change to A view. I cannot find a way to change to A view. Or is it not A view?