# How does GIF keyboard capture what has been typed in android?

Tags: android, keyboard, accessibility-api

I recently had a chance to look at a GIF Keyboard (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riffsy.FBMGIFApp)

It is able to figure out what has been typed after '#' in whatsapp, messenger and other platforms.

I have been looking around and looking for a way to replicate that behavior.

I have been looking at the accessibility api of android. But how does one track what has been typed in by the user on the soft keyboard?

[Custom keyboard like gif keyboard in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395655/custom-keyboard-like-gif-keyboard-in-android) - Unlike this, i do not want to implement my own keyboard, rather it should work with the current keyboard.

Is there some kind of broadcast that i could listen to?
Is this a feature of Whatsapp to allow the keys to be tracked or is it the OS?

Any help on this greatly appreciated.

PS: I know i should post solutions i have tried so far, but there has really been nothing substantial that i found after days of investigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. 
I achieved this by using an accessibility service and calling event.getText to get the text in the currently focused EditText

```
public class MyKeyboardAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {


@Override
public void onServiceConnected() {
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
    setServiceInfo(info);
}

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
     String text = event.getText();
     ...
}
```